# Finding character duplicates in R

Tags: r

I have two columns in R, first.name and last.name. I want to find people who've entered their first or last name twice. I wrote this to find exact equality --

```
data.frame[df$first.name == df$last.name,].
```

However, those only return exact equality between rows. For example, people who wrote `"George King"` in the `first.name` field and `"George King"` in the `last.name` field. But I also want to find someone who wrote `"George"` in the `first.name` column and `"George King"` in the last name column.

I need some sort of function that looks for a row containing similar characters, but not necessarily the exact same characters.

Comment: If "similar characters" means "first.name is a subset of last.name", then @generic_user's answer will be helpful. Otherwise, you may want to read up on [fuzzy pattern matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_recognition).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the `grep` family of functions

```
1> x = c('George', 'George King')
1> grepl(x[1],x[2])
[1] TRUE

?grepl
```

Note that in a data frame you'd need to run these line-by-line, because `grepl` doesn't take vector input.  Use some sort of `apply` strategy

Comment: You don't need to run these line-by-line. Use `sapply()`.

Comment: Wouldn't this be a use case for `mapply`?

Comment: When I try to install the grep package I get: Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘grep’ is not available (for R version 3.2.1)

Comment: `grep` and its cousins are part of base.  You shouldn't need to install any packages

Comment: it  claims it cannot find function "grep1" when I write grep1(DSCC[2], DSCC[3])

Comment: it's a lower-case L.  stands for "logical"  :)